# Naming modules with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to figure out how to name modules without using the relative path of the module itself.

For example:

Instead of doing this:

```
//module is defined in app/js/routers.js
define('app/js/routers',['app/js/currentView'],function(currentView) {

});
```

I would rather do this:

```
//module is defined in app/js/routers.js
define('routers',['app/js/currentView'],function(currentView) {

});
```

is this possible or is it a bad idea? Obviously, the names that you give each module would have to be unique. I guess I just don't the see point of the optional first parameter in the define call if it has to be same as the path of script it's contained in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess I just don't the see point of the optional first parameter in the define call if it has to be same as the path of script it's contained in.

Yep, if you are going to put the module in a file whose path, relative to the `baseURL` you give in your RequireJS configuration, is the name of the module, then you do *not* have to provide a module name to `define`. In fact, you *should not* give a module name in this case. The [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) states:

> These [i.e. module names] are normally generated by the optimization tool. You can explicitly name modules yourself, but it makes the modules less portable -- if you move the file to another directory you will need to change the name. **It is normally best to avoid coding in a name for the module and just let the optimization tool burn in the module names.** The optimization tool needs to add the names so that more than one module can be bundled in a file, to allow for faster loading in the browser.

(Emphasis added.)

Comment: Hey Louis, thanks, I think it would be really cool if RequireJS allowed you to put your own names into the modules according some convention, like define('name*',[],function(){}). (putting a start after the module name).Thinking about it I don't really see why not, but there probably is a good reason.